# How can I store a string in an sqlite3 Database on iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'd like to see some sample code for that. Any good Tutorial-Link is also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a link to the [SQLite3 C/C++ Intro](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

In the past, I've used the [sqlite3_exec](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)() function to execute SQL statements instead of the harder prepared statement API.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would in any SQL database.